# Crypto library suitable for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cryptography

I'm looking for a crypto library to use with Objective-C code. There is a C++ library which is too big for my needs. It's 20 mb when compiled. I think a C library would be perfect to use with Objective-C. 
Here is my needs for this library:
AES (Rijndael)
CFB Mode
SHA1
SHA256
HMAC-SHA1
HMAC-SHA256
PBKDF2

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I link against [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/) for cryptography in my Objective-C projects. If you're using OS X, this is already installed on every user's machine. There's also a cocoa framework called [SSCrypto](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) which provides Objective-C wrappers for openssl, which makes the C-based openssl library a little easier to use.

Answer (score 19):

The usual/official way to do this is to `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`, which is the CommonCrypto library. Then, you can use functions like `CC_MD5()`, `CC_SHA()`, `CC_HMac()`, etc.

The [CommonCrypto `man` page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html) has links to all the available functions.

Comment: Matt has the better answer here, unless you're looking for portability to other OS's. OpenSSL is basically there for compatibility only. Apple's own projects either use or are migrating to CommonCrypto or Keychain Services.

Comment: Apple's sample code for CommonCrypto can be found here: https://opensource.apple.com//source/CommonCrypto/

Answer (score 1):

I started a libsodium/NaCl wrapper for Objective-C at https://github.com/gabriel/NACL