# Get a file's md5/sha1 checksum

Tags: macos, md5, sha1

I have found two functions to count md5 and sha 1 in Objective C. Here's the code:

```
-(void)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input {
NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

uint8_t digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_MD5(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

NSMutableString* ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",digest[i]];
}
NSLog (@"%@",ret);
}

-(void) SHA1digest:(NSString*)input{
NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH *2];

for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

NSLog (@"%@", output);
}
```

I get these checksums:

```
2010-11-04 20:38:01.962 MD5 Counter[88118:a0f] c8142be71e8ed4625c4f27eb573835f5
2010-11-04 20:38:01.964 MD5 Counter[88118:a0f] ba7ff5f68edef52dd89a92c075b88f247f3ef9aa
```

However, the real sums are:
SHA1: 1c0d5ea45464e336fcb38c644dc125c3a16b5493

MD5: e8f4d590c8fe62386844d6a2248ae609

Where is the mistake? Help me, please!

Comment: Knodel, you have completely changed the question.  You should really started a new one or at least just appended the new stuff to the old one.  Now the answers don't make sense in the context of the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll start a new question then. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the CommonCrypto C API.  The functions are documented in section 3CC of the [man pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007259).  In particular the [CC_md5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CC_MD5.3cc.html) and [CC_sha1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CC_SHA1.3cc.html) function families will be of interest to you.

Comment: I have googled this function families but this doesn't work. Please, have a look at my updated post

Comment: @Knodel, to be honest, I don't know much about Objective-C, but something like `allowLossyConversion:YES` sounds like it's going to cause problems. MD5 and SHA-1 are precisely designed to produce a different result if the input changes even slightly, so any sort of implicit conversion is likely to make it produce a different output. I'd try to use the binary data from the file, rather than any sort of text string conversion (not even sure if you're still working with files now that you've changed the question).

Comment: @Knodel: Bruno is correct.  It is probable that the conversion is effectively changing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the Mac AppStore restrictions are, but you might be able to call out the `md5` command. It's is installed by default on OSX and computes the MD5 checksum of the file given as an argument.

Comment: How can it be used in Obj-C context?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but I guess there is an `exec` equivalent in Obj-C that lets you call external commands. Alternatively, you might be able to use the OpenSSL API, which has functions for MD5 and SHA-1 computation (you'd probably need to read the content of the file and feed it to them). This might be relevant for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276798/crypto-library-suitable-for-objective-c

Comment: I don't think that's a good option... There should be a function to do this

Comment: Which one? Calling the external command or the OpenSSL API? (I'd agree calling the external command would be my least favourite choice between the these choices.)