# How to encrypt files in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, encryption, aes

How can I encrypt (256 bit AES) files on a Mac in a Cocoa application? I've been having trouble with this for a very long time. Also, would I have to extract the contents of the file before I encrypt? Clear step by step instructions would be much appreciated. I am a noobie when it comes to cryptography.

Comment: AES doesn’t deal with passwords. You need to choose a key derivation algorithm first, and use this algorithm to derive an AES key from a given password. Before asking about the programming part of your problem, I recommend you visit http://security.stackexchange.com and first define what algorithms & protocols you need for your solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crypto library suitable for Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276798/crypto-library-suitable-for-objective-c)

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solutions in [THIS SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276798/crypto-library-suitable-for-objective-c), you might want to have a look at [Mac GNU PG](http://macgpg.sourceforge.net/)